# Problem with formatting when Trying to set copy richtext (C#)

Tags: c#, string, text, formatting

How to reproduce:

1. I made a richTextBox in Visual Studio (UI tool)
2. I made a richTextBox2 in Visual Studio (UI tool)
3. In any text Editor, I Write some Letters, and add some rich format to them for example Color the text red
4. I copy this on the first richTextBox, all good.
5. Then IN code I ran this: richTextBox2.text = richTextBox.text;

It would copy the text but without the formatting. That's my issue.

Comment: Please, provide more code and better explain your question, so that we can help you.

Comment: Everything I did is stated.. String1 has bullet points, colors, etc. then I Run this "String2.text = String1.text" and String2 would lose all of the formatting in String1

Comment: 1) Select all text in trb1. 2) remove all Text from rtb2 (or set the selectionStart) and 3) rtb2.SelectedText = rtb1.SelectedText.

Comment: try with `richTextBox2.Rtf = richTextBox2.Rtf;`. Property `Text` contains only plain text.

Answer (score 1):

OK I temporarily fixed it using this:

```
        richTextBox1.Copy();
        richTextBox2.Paste();
```